# Pandas: Generate Sequential Timestamp with Jump

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, timestamp

I have a df with the following index

```
df.index
>>> [2010-01-04 10:00:00, ..., 2010-12-31 16:00:00]
```

The main column is `volume`.

In the timestamp sequence, weekends and some other weekdays are not present. I want to resample my time index to have the aggregate sum of volume per minute. So I do the following:

`df = df.resample('60S', how=sum)`

There are some missing minutes. In other words, there are minutes where there are no trades. I want to include these missing minutes and add a 0 to the column `volume`. 
To solve this, I would usually do something like:

```
new_range = pd.date_range('20110104 09:30:00','20111231 16:00:00',
                          freq='60s')+df.index
df = df.reindex(new_range)
df = df.between_time(start_time='10:00', end_time='16:00') # time interval per day that I want
df = df.fillna(0)
```

But now I am stuck with unwanted dates like the weekends and some other days. How can I get rid of the dates that were not originally in my timestamp index?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just construct the range of datetimes you want and reindex to it.

Entire range

```
In [9]: rng = pd.date_range('20130101 09:00','20130110 16:00',freq='30T')

In [10]: rng
Out[10]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-01-01 09:00:00, ..., 2013-01-10 16:00:00]
Length: 447, Freq: 30T, Timezone: None
```

Eliminate times out of range

```
In [11]: rng = rng.take(rng.indexer_between_time('09:30','16:00'))

In [12]: rng
Out[12]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-01-01 09:30:00, ..., 2013-01-10 16:00:00]
Length: 140, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Eliminate non-weekdays

```
In [13]: rng = rng[rng.weekday<5]

In [14]: rng
Out[14]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-01-01 09:30:00, ..., 2013-01-10 16:00:00]
Length: 112, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Just looking at the values, you prob want `df.reindex(index=rng)`

```
In [15]: rng.to_series()
Out[15]: 
2013-01-01 09:30:00   2013-01-01 09:30:00
2013-01-01 10:00:00   2013-01-01 10:00:00
2013-01-01 10:30:00   2013-01-01 10:30:00
2013-01-01 11:00:00   2013-01-01 11:00:00
2013-01-01 11:30:00   2013-01-01 11:30:00
2013-01-01 12:00:00   2013-01-01 12:00:00
2013-01-01 12:30:00   2013-01-01 12:30:00
2013-01-01 13:00:00   2013-01-01 13:00:00
2013-01-01 13:30:00   2013-01-01 13:30:00
2013-01-01 14:00:00   2013-01-01 14:00:00
2013-01-01 14:30:00   2013-01-01 14:30:00
2013-01-01 15:00:00   2013-01-01 15:00:00
2013-01-01 15:30:00   2013-01-01 15:30:00
2013-01-01 16:00:00   2013-01-01 16:00:00
2013-01-02 09:30:00   2013-01-02 09:30:00
...
2013-01-09 16:00:00   2013-01-09 16:00:00
2013-01-10 09:30:00   2013-01-10 09:30:00
2013-01-10 10:00:00   2013-01-10 10:00:00
2013-01-10 10:30:00   2013-01-10 10:30:00
2013-01-10 11:00:00   2013-01-10 11:00:00
2013-01-10 11:30:00   2013-01-10 11:30:00
2013-01-10 12:00:00   2013-01-10 12:00:00
2013-01-10 12:30:00   2013-01-10 12:30:00
2013-01-10 13:00:00   2013-01-10 13:00:00
2013-01-10 13:30:00   2013-01-10 13:30:00
2013-01-10 14:00:00   2013-01-10 14:00:00
2013-01-10 14:30:00   2013-01-10 14:30:00
2013-01-10 15:00:00   2013-01-10 15:00:00
2013-01-10 15:30:00   2013-01-10 15:30:00
2013-01-10 16:00:00   2013-01-10 16:00:00
Length: 112
```

You could also start with a constructed business day freq series (and/or add custom business day if you want holidays, new in 0.14.0, see [here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/timeseries.html#timeseries-holiday)